# Query the Partner Community Account via SOQL

Tags: soql, partner-communities

I was updating test classes in our org to get more code coverage and stumbled upon all those obviously being for our partner community. Now there is this SiteRegisterController, which the Salesforce standard help page also offers:

[Site Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites.htm)

The problem is that this controller is only covered to 82% which drags down our overall code coverage. Now I've seen that the  is hard-coded, something I do not like to have in my org. That's why I ask if it is possible to query for that partner account other than by name as I can't seem to find a field like "enabledForPartner" or something.